# Push array into array of object using map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
var json = [{
  "tracks": get_track('0IMzbxnAqwRi6sm9s5oOJO')
}];
$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2))

function get_track(id) {
  $.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/" + id + "/tracks", function(data, status) {
    var array = [];
    data.items.map(function(item) {
      return array.push(item.name);
    });

    console.log(array);

  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yjmafdrz/

In return item.name, I can get my array's item, but it just can't be append to my array of object, anyone know why?

Comment: @Arun P My question can't be answer there.

Comment: Since `get_track` has an asynchronous method and its callback will be executed after `get_track` has returned the value(undefined).

Comment: @arun P means what? I do the appending in the get_track function?

Comment: @gurvinder372 how about this? https://jsfiddle.net/tfsfg23o/ I have 2 calls here.

Comment: answer remains same, asynch operations and callbacks don't return values

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yjmafdrz/1/